# How Do I Undraft A PR?

Tags: github, pull-request

I made a PR. Several changes were requested. I carried out those changes. The repository maintainers are happy with the changes, but requested that I 'Undraft' the PR; how do I go about undrafting it?

Comment: Did you do any research? https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/changing-the-stage-of-a-pull-request, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Scroll through the body of the PR and click the `Ready for review` button.

[image: undraft a pr]